# Unable to fetch some rows from aerospike sets using Spring Spikefy ORM

Tags: java, spring, aerospike

I have some some rows for which fetch via my application logic is not working.
For the ones for which it is working, I observed that the PK shows up in the select * query -

```
  aql> select * from dummy.test_template_content where template="notification_working"
+-----++-----+-------------------------+
| PK  | id   | template                |
+-----++-----+-------------------------+
| 11  | 11   | "notification_working"  |
+-----+--------------------------------+
```

However, for the ones not working, it shows like this (without PK) -

```
  aql> select * from dummy.test_template_content where template="notification_failing"
+-----+-------------------------+
| id  | template                |
+-----+-------------------------+
| 115 | "notification_failing" |
+-----+-------------------------+
```

I have inserted the second one now and only these are the ones not working. The others were already present in the set. Here is the query I had used to insert -

```
insert into dummy.test_template_content(PK,id,template) values(115,115,"notification_failing")
```

**There is index on the template column.**

```
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| ns                  | bin            | indextype | set                                 | state | indexname                               | path           | type      |
+---------------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------+----------------+-----------+
| "dummy"             | "template"     | "NONE"    | "test_template_content"        | "RW"  | "msg_template"                          | "template"     | "STRING"  |
```

Following is the logic which gets the records based on "template" field.

```
Statement stmt = new Statement();
        stmt.setNamespace(asconf.getNamespace());
        stmt.setSetName("test_template_content");
        stmt.setFilters(Filter.equal("template", trigger));

        RecordSet rs = null;
        try{
            rs = client.query(null, stmt); 
            while(rs != null && rs.next()){
                Record record = rs.getRecord();
                MessageTemplateContent content = sfy.map(MessageTemplateContent.class, rs.getKey(), record);
                if(content.channel().equals(channel)) //does not go to this line in my template's case - exception thrown
                    return Optional.<Template> of(content);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Error while fetching template for trigger {}, channel {}", trigger, channel, e);

        }finally{
            if(rs != null)
                rs.close();
        }

        return Optional.absent();
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to read existing rows in aerospike db using Spring's Spikefy ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024022/unable-to-read-existing-rows-in-aerospike-db-using-springs-spikefy-orm)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you see the PK column on the AQL output or not depends on how you created the record in terms of its write policy. In AQL, if you SET KEY_SEND TRUE, then PK will be returned. By default KEY_SEND is FALSE. See below:

```
aql> select * from ns1.user
0 rows in set (0.038 secs)

OK  [-- no records in the set to start with]

aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (1, 'Raj', 24)
OK, 1 record affected.  [-- inserted one record, with key_send false by default]

aql> select * from ns1.user
+-------+-----+
| name  | age |
+-------+-----+
| "Raj" | 24  |
+-------+-----+
1 row in set (0.038 secs)

OK  [-- you don't see PK column]

aql> SET KEY_SEND TRUE
KEY_SEND = true
aql> insert into ns1.user (pk, name, age) values (2, 'Kumar', 25)
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> select * from ns1.user
+---------+-----+----+
| name    | age | PK |
+---------+-----+----+
| "Raj"   | 24  |    |   [-- no PK entry for this record]
| "Kumar" | 25  | 2  |   [-- this was inserted with KEY_SEND TRUE]
+---------+-----+----+
2 rows in set (0.037 secs)

OK
```